# Which comes first? Heart of the Swarm or Wings of Liberty?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm quite confused as which Starcraft 2 game to buy first?

If I buy Heart of Swarm will I'll be able to play in Wings of Liberty too? or no?

Comment: Wings of Liberty. You can always check the release date of each via google though so you can check which comes first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heart of the Swarm is an *expansion pack*, not a standalone game. You HAVE to have bought Wings of Liberty *as well* in order to play it.

The story of Heart of the Swarm also continues on from where it left off in Wings of Liberty, so you'll find some spoilers if you try and complete Heart of the Swarm first.

To quote the Starcraft 2 [FAQ](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/heart-of-the-swarm-preview/faq) (some snips to avoid spoilers):

> Heart of the Swarm is the first expansion set to Blizzard Entertainment’s sci-fi real time strategy game, StarCraft II: Wings of Liberty. Heart of the Swarm continues the epic story from Wings of Liberty with an all-new campaign that focuses on Kerrigan. New multiplayer content will also be included in the expansion, as well as new features and upgrades to the Battle.net online platform.

So the answer, play Wings of Liberty first.

Comment: If i buy wings of liberty can i have the heart of swarm for free? no?

Comment: @gamdevNoobie doubt it otherwise everyone who brought Wings of Liberty years ago would get Heart of the Swarm for free and Blizzard wouldn't make any money, you might find some sort of deal pack with both in it but i very much doubt it

Comment: @gamdevNoobie - No. You must buy both if you want Heart of the Swarm as well

Comment: Exception: you can download the [SC2 Starter Edition](https://us.battle.net/account/activation/landing.html?product=S2&trial) and use [spawning](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/10145834) to play HotS multiplayer. Basically, if a friend with HotS invites you to a party, you can play HotS multiplayer.

Comment: @Wikwocket - Neat trick! I'll remember that next time I need to convince a friend to buy the game :)

Comment: @Wikwocket One thing you forgot to mention: the "spawned" friend can only play as the Terran, so if you want to play as any other race you have to actually buy the game.

Comment: @jacen.garriss Actually, I believe spawned players can play as any race, as long as they are in a party with someone with the full game. My wife plays this way and it gives her the race selection UI for league play.

Comment: @Wikwocket It does show the race Selection UI, but I believe that Zerg and Protoss are grayed out. I've "spawned" severely friends to get them interested in Starcraft, but they only been able to play as Terran.

Comment: Interestingly, Blizzard has announced that Legacy of the Void *will* be a standalone game, and will not require Wings of Liberty or Heart of the Swarm.

Comment: @RavenDreamer - really? Weird. It's probably to bring in new players. I guess that they didn't have near enough people purchase both Wings of Liberty and Heart of the Swarm when the latter came out, and they don't want to lock People into buying effectively 3 copies of the same game.

Comment: If you only have Wings of Liberty, you can play Heart of the Swarm if you team up with a friend that bought Hearth of the Swarm.

Answer (score 0):

You have to play wings of liberty first unless you just want to play multiplayer only. I find Hearts of the swarm is more fun to play in multiplayer.